# Post to wall to multiple friends using ios facebook sdk ios 7

Tags: ios

I am using Facebook SDK, i have list of friends Facebook id. how to post message to friends wall. I need sample for post message to multiple friends.

Comment: you can use a for loop !!

Comment: sorry its not correct way.. because its open dialog view.